# Можно ли с помощью Java нажать кнопку на сайте?

Tags: java

Здравствуйте,допустим на этом сайте я хочу с помощью java нажать на кнопку-"Задать вопрос". По средствам чего это можно сделать и можно ли вообще?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для автоматизации/имитации работы браузера обычно используют [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) с драйвером, оборачивающим какой-либо браузер. Нажатие кнопки будет выглядеть так:

```
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://ru.stackoverflow.com");
WebElement el = driver.findElementById("nav-askquestion");
el.click();
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но когда я откомпилировал ваш код у меня вылетела ошибка 
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property;

Comment: @user238445 вы уже прочитали доку по Selenium, установили chromedriver?

Comment: Спасибо большое,разобрался.Вы мне очень помогли